# how to get output from two for loops?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting, text-files

I have the following input.txt file:

```
tr=min;JohnLoeffler
te=min;TimWalter
```

The aim of the batch file I want is to give me:

```
tr min;JohnLoeffler
te min;TimWalter
```

and the my batch file is:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=;" %%a in (E:\input.txt) do (
echo.%%a>current.tok
E:\ProtocoI\%%b
for /f " tokens=* delims= " %%a in (E:\input.txt) do (
call :sub1 %%a
)
GOTO :EOF
:sub1
echo %1 %2
echo.%1 %2; %%b;!RESULT!>>output.txt
)
GOTO :EOF
```

however the output I get is:

```
tr min; %b;
te min; %b;
```

note that I need that current.tok for using in one further function and the second for loop is for dropping equal sign in te=min and tr=min. now I don't know how to work with these two for loops to have the correct mentioned output.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advace,
HOda

Comment: `:sub1` in inside a block of code, you have to move it outside the parentheses.

Comment: @Arescet you mean outside the parentheses of second for loop?

Comment: Yes, a label cannot be within a loop, or anything else that is between parentheses. it must be placed outside. It will either run into a syntax error or behave erratically..

Comment: @Arescet but it's already outside the parentheses of second for loop

Comment: You may use this: `for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (E:\input.txt) do echo %%a %%b`

Comment: @Aacini I don't have problem for getting a, but it's b that I cannot get

Comment: Did you tested my line of code? I mean, use it instead _your whole program_. You may even run it from the command-line (with single percent signs).

Comment: HI Aacini, if I put Parentheses around your line to redirect output like in this worling line: `(for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==;" %%A in (input.txt) do @Echo %%A %%B;%%C)>Output.txt` I get the same flaw mentioned by Compo/Magoo

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what such flaw is. If you use this code with the "input.txt file" posted in this question, then you get _exactly the same output_ you wrote below "The aim of the batch file I want is to give me:"... Did you tested it?

Comment: Here. [This site](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html), go to the "BUGS" section, this explains the error most likely causing bad values in your program. the label `:sub1` is inside the paretheses of the `for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=;" %%a in (E:\input.txt) do ( ...` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, *I have had to guess a little as to what you were trying to achieve*.

```dos
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(Set SrcFile=E:\input.txt)

For /F "UseBackQ EOL== Tokens=1-2* Delims==;" %%A In ("%SrcFile%") Do (
    >current.tok Echo=%%A=%%B
    >>E:\ProtocoI\%%C\output.txt Echo=%%A %%B; %%C; !RESULT!)
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, you wouldn't believe how difficult it is to type on an android phone with predictive text into a forum!

Comment: I'd suggest the `EOL==  ` is counterproductive and better omitted. It's not clear where `result` spirits in from. In OP's original, `%%a` is illegally re-used and `%%b` is out-of-scope in the subroutine. The key is to use the delimiters to tokenise properly and reconstruct the data in `current.tok` which we're forced to assume is `str1=str2` for lack of further information. As for the data in the `output.txt` file(s) - well - good guess, but overloading the crystal ball somewhat...

Comment: It is my understanding that setting EOL to the same as DELIMS effectively bypasses the crazy default EOL of a semi-colon and ensures that all lines are read. _(I thought this necessary as the OP was reading a file strewn with semi-colons)_. The OP has stated that this is part of a script, as I have no idea where !RESULT! comes I was not in a position to correct it to the more likely %RESULT% or verify its use.

Comment: Not heard about EOL=DELIMS, but I've done precious little experimenting with EOL. Since it's 2:25am here, I'll do some experiments tomorrow, if I remember...